# Sphinx build rst to html single page

Tags: python-sphinx

I need to build HTML from RST with `sphinx-build`. Now I use command:

```
os.system("sphinx-build -b singlehtml -T -D html_add_permalinks=None -D extensions='sphinx.ext.autodoc' -D master_doc='index' -C /my/doc /tmp/sphinx")
```

But as result it gives complicated HTML with css and JS. But I need only one HTML page with all combined RST files. Maybe even without table of content.  Or if it is possible with table of content that works without JS.
I searched for such option in official documentation a lot but did not find what I need.

Please help if somebody knows how to do it.

Comment: sphinx generates html files using [themes](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html). Most themes will use a CSS file to avoid copying the style from html file to html file. Check the different themes (`-D html_theme=basic` for instance) and see already if there is a JS file. You can copy the theme and have the css file be included inline by editing, for the basic theme, `basic/layout.html`.

Comment: What do you mean by "complicated HTML"? There should be a single HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

To convert to pure HTML you better use https://pandoc.org/

Alternatively you could post-process the Sphinx generated HTML to remove all CSS and Javascript.